# If statement not working even after fulfilling condition

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a solution to a problem of finding sum of even digits of number.
Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mySum=EvenDigitSum.getEvenDigitSum(879);
        System.out.println(mySum);
    }
}
```

Above in main Method.

```
Even DigitSum
public class EvenDigitSum {
    public static int getEvenDigitSum(int number){
       int sum=0;
        if (number<0){
            return -1;
        }else {
            while (number>0){
                int lastDigit=(number%10);
                System.out.println("last digit"+lastDigit);
                if (lastDigit%2==0){
                    sum=(sum+lastDigit);
                    System.out.println("my sum"+sum);
                }
                number/=10;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

here I have got 2 print statements one in while loop and other in if statement. The one in while loop gives correct output but one in if statement never gives one.
In main method my number is 879 which has 8 so for 8 if statement should work but it is not working.My final sum of even digits is coming 0.

got mistake used / instead of %

Comment: so you expect 8/2 to be 0? why?

Comment: `if` statements will do precisely what you ask them to do: the issue here is your assumptions.

Comment: i got very silly mistake should use modulo

Comment: Did you run your code with a debugger? If you are using an IDE then it should have a debugger. If you are not using an IDE, I think you should consider it. A popular one is [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Comment: am newbie so still exploring but a small mistake got me-3. and banned for 2 days

Comment: Even without an IDE a simple print statement would allow an assumption check. We all make silly mistakes--the trick is to use those silly mistakes to develop a debugging process. I *always* start by assuming I've done something stupid and either don't understand the results of an expression (e.g., the `if` condition) or how to use a method/library/etc.

Comment: Yeah will take care from next time and will not hurry

Comment: @DivyangBhamat It's a process. We'll always make dumb mistakes, sometimes costly ones, due to haste, ignorance, etc. It gets better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```java
if (lastDigit / 2 == 0)
```

You're checking if half of the last digit is 0. Of course, this will only happen if the digit is 0 or 1. Instead, use `% 2` to get the remainder:

```java
if (lastDigit % 2 == 0)
```